# Eclipse JDT Code Formatter: Indent parameter in IF-Statement

Tags: eclipse, if-statement, formatter, eclipse-jdt

I have a questions regarding the Eclipse code formatter in JDT:

How can I make Eclipse format the following code in the given way:

```
BEFORE
if (objectA.getFoo().equals(objectB.getFoo()) && (objectA.getBar().equals(objectB.getBar()) || resultOfAnotherTest)){
...
}

AFTER
if (objectA.getFoo().equals(objectB.getFoo()) 
    && (objectA.getBar().equals(objectB.getBar()) 
        || resultOfAnotherTest)){
...
}
```

A second example:

```
BEFORE
if (foo1 == foo2 && bar1 == bar2 && blub1 == blub2 && !braindead){
...
}

AFTER
if (foo1 == foo2 
    && bar1 == bar2 
    && blub1 == blub2 
    && !braindead){
...
}
```

Logical operators shall signal line wrapping.
Structuring brackets shall signal indention depth.