# Formatting of new line indentation of if conditions in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, indentation, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

In Eclipse (4.4) CDT (8.5) on windows (7) the indentation of new lines within `if` and `else if` conditions does not make sense to me. Where in eclipse is this set?

I have tried looking in Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter but could not see any relevant setting.

An example where I hit the return key as I type the conditions or select the lines and press Ctrl+I ("Fix Indentation"). Note that the first four lines all have the same indentation despite differing levels of nesting. The following fifth line indents *two* more levels than the preceding line, as does the seventh line both with no apparent relation to the level of nesting.

```
else if (((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Byte) && (qcn >= 1)
        && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Process_Call) 
        && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR)) 
        || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Word) && (qcn >=2) 
                && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR)) 
                || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Block_Write) 
                        && (qcn >= (CMD_Number_Bytes_max + 1)))) {
    e = EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I would prefer something along the lines of the following:

```
else if (((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Byte) && (qcn >= 1)
                && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Process_Call) 
                && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR)) 
            || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Word) && (qcn >=2) 
                && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR)) 
            || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Block_Write) 
                && (qcn >= (CMD_Number_Bytes_max + 1)))) {
    e = EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Is it possible to change this?
Also if someone could comment with an explanation of the current indentation/nesting formatting it would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Realised this may be similar to [Eclipse JDT Code Formatter: Indent parameter in IF-Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336653/eclipse-jdt-code-formatter-indent-parameter-in-if-statement)

Comment: You can define your own style rules in eclipse' preference dialog.

Comment: @flutter But how to do this for the `if`/`if else` conditions? My question pretty much states that I have looked in those preferences but did not see how to do this. Thanks

Comment: The original indentation looks logical to me. The one you want does not. Hint: Checkt the parenthesis nesting levels.

Comment: @Olaf I'm afraid I don't understand. The first 4 conditions that are AND'd to make up the first 3 lines are all sub-conditions that are OR'd with 2 more conditions each of which also consist of AND'd sub-conditions. I would have though then that the OR lines should be less indented than the AND lines. I guess with forward only reading this allows the first 4 lines to be correct, but it does not explain the continued indentation of the last 3, nor the use of double indentation on those lines rather than single. Could you explain further? Thanks

Comment: @Olaf This is why I originally had the C/C++ tags you removed, because the explanation may relate to the actual code, not solely its layout.

Comment: @Toby: It still is not specific to the languages, but Eclipse.

Comment: @Olaf each language in Eclipse has its own code formatters built on some common infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to change this?

Yes. With the default indentation strategy (K&R built-in) I get the same as you with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, but if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (format code) I get the following.

```c
} else if (((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Byte) && (qcn >= 1)
        && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Process_Call)
        && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR))
        || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Word) && (qcn >= 2)
                && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR))
        || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Block_Write)
                && (qcn >= (CMD_Number_Bytes_max + 1)))) {
```

If you want to get column alignment, rather than simple indentation on continued lines, create your own formatting profile and change the following:

- *Indentation* tab -> *Tab policy* to either *Spaces only* or *Mixed*

  - With the default of *Tabs only* the indents will be to the next tab stop
- *Line Wrapping* tab -> *Expressions*/*Binary Expressions* set *Indentation policy* to *Indent on column*

This is what you end up with when you format (but not when you simply correct indentation):

```c
} else if (((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Byte) && (qcn >= 1)
            && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Process_Call)
            && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR))
           || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Write_Word) && (qcn >= 2)
               && (rp != SMB_Protocol_Block_WR))
           || ((wp == SMB_Protocol_Block_Write) && (qcn
                   >= (CMD_Number_Bytes_max + 1)))) {
```

Here are screenshots showing the settings:

[image: spaces instead of tabs]

and

[image: indentation policy]

Comment: Wow thanks Jonah! This is very close to what I want. So close in fact I think it actually answers the question I asked. 
I'll ask another one for the difference. (I've been trying to implement GNU style [https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Formatting.html#Formatting] within CDT, where the AND & OR operators begin the new lines)

Comment: I'll keep my eye out for the new one you submit, I normally watch eclipse-cdt tag, so I should see it there.